# Как процессор обрабатывает команды разной длины если слово фиксированной длины?

Tags: cpu, процессор, микроархитектура

Сначала думал, что если команда длиннее машинного слова, то происходит выборка из следующего машинного слова, но прочитал, что в УУ передаются данные размера максимальной длины команды, т.е. если максимальная длина - 5 байтов, то на УУ подаются 5 байтов. Что тогда определяет машинное слово?

Comment: Что за «УУ»?  Если брать x86, то в этой архитектуре инструкция может иметь размер до 15 байт. Но никто не ограничивает размер регистра инструкций 64 битами. Так и считывает, несколько слов, а потом склеивает. Что еще остается делать, если за раз нельзя прочитать? Как *конкретно* считывает, зависит от самого чипа.

Comment: Вот [комментарий](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449128/x86-64-architecture-how-does-it-handle-instructions-larger-than-64-bits#comment1127306_449128) человека на эту тему, который по его словам, работал в Intel.

Comment: @eanmos УУ - устройство управления. Я смотрел лекции по risc-v, где инструкции фиксированного размера, и их длина равна машинному слову, а в x86 не совсем понятно как процессор работает с машинным словом. По risc-v там предлагается вариант микроархитектуры, а по x86 таких лекций не нашел. Может книги какие поискать ..

Comment: @eanmos как я понял он считывает по 64 байта (x86-64) пока не считает всю инструкцию. Это он делает на определенной стадии конвеера, т.е. пока не считает полностью, другие команды ждут своей очереди.

Comment: В книгах конкретику вряд ли найдете. Все-такие дизайн чипов Intel и AMD находится под NDA. Есть такой исследователь CPU, Агнер Фог. У него есть [документ](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjkpu7piNjxAhUnlIsKHfl0DNkQFjAXegQIChAC&usg=AOvVaw2lPuz1NHSG1MeJ94RvuDtq&cshid=1625905273995) с описанием микроархитектур процессоров Intel и AMD. Обратите внимание, например, на раздел 6.2.

Comment: @eanmos спасибо, посмотрю